# Помогите плес горит лаба

Tags: c++

1. Реализуйте модуль, подключение которого перегружает операции помещения в
   поток вывода и извлечение из потока ввода для класса, содержащего методы разложения
   функции `ln(1+x)` в ряд Тейлора. На экран должно выводиться `n` первых слагаемых формулы
   Тейлора. Значение `n` определяет пользователь.
2. Реализуйте модуль, пишите программу, реализующую класс для работы с целыми числами, не превышающими 254. Для данного класса реализуйте перегрузку операции сложения так, чтобы результатом сложения было побитовое ИЛИ.

Comment: **Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос.** Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Comment: @Onleg Решил вашу задачу, [смотрите мой ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1225173/267338), надеюсь решил верно! Если не верно, сообщайте, поправлю.

Comment: @Onleg Хотелось бы чтобы вы оставили прошлый вопрос также. Про вывод ряда тэйлора в поток. Если вам нужно ещё вопросы решить, то как минимум просто добавьте в конец доп текст, не удаляя прошлого, если не сказать что можно отдельный StackOverflow пост с вопросом сделать. Т.к. если вы удалили прошлый вопрос то уже не понятно что отвечает [мой ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1225173/267338), нужно изначальный текст не удалять.

Comment: @Onleg Реализовал кроме 1-го ещё 2-й вопрос [в моём ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1225173/267338), проверьте обав.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

**Вопрос 1**

Решил помочь вам, закодировал решение вашей задачи в том виде в каком я понял вашу задачу.

Сделал даже немного больше, кроме вывода ряда в консоль ещё сделал ввод значения любой точки X и вывод значения ряда в этой точке, сделал это только для того чтобы проверить корректность закодированной формулы.

Не забудьте что нужно вводить такие a и x, что -1 < a*x < 1, иначе ряд не сойдётся.

Также ещё [реализовал вариант](https://tio.run/##jVXNTttAEL77KUYgIZuAA0gVUgy50F576q1qo8UxsIpjW/aapq2Q@GmL1B@QeuylUp8gpSAgFHiF3SeiM7tOcEKA@mDvzs7uzvfNN2M/SWb9kEXrNzfVKmwIkWS1ajWI3De8xZOgyZkbp@tVmlVfsLdhnDayIOVBNvmciTxlYSOM11nKxUbbsiZ55Id5M4ClzcAXcVovWXiciTRg7bLNbzOxUbcsDCDLwBy/Emfw3kry1ZD7NQvwwbjkD3klL9WO2lXbak/21K68UtsuyO/qi9qXZ2pHXsgTeYmjQ0CXQ3ksuyB/oe0cV9CXpsfyApflqezSMnpf4u6PEM0Ac/VNgwjsjL8LGoKWmjGGEgBzMCoonsLWgmWY9wbWtTiF/kaOS3MefpYg8qBS4eXt9GQNN8mzjcYq81t2y/GGFlswvQyzDKaBQRVsewFHHCow7@BgMFtwStu2rNs3EYbEyCMk7RjkEchrpAApkz2wEXZXXiMhZ/KvPFHbIHuGW3xfqK@OYWIz5k14mrcTOxPNWq3IHUxBFufCAT@OMlFCdA90BElG2xlLwVCYFA7wWXmu41Hf1Af1AbP5Ce2YV7VLGC7UgdqBDpAO0HptMg42r8wXYQ/YxShhiQJ4yV/RYAI567yeoKFtmBxmnK8V9nLUzpBL@dwJdJ14kPxhVcqT@1Rp4i4EtRK3k1wEdjHtjNFcSuzO/Kf0HuY/hcpywdA0tMYosEOkjaLUOwMs/QhSr8CdpHyTicCUqxaMqf8lE3Qdb/GsLc@yiJyfpDqk4I8u5VNMN3JyRdkkPkxlk@loII3usIZdi0chjwIYkWacBCnDW3WSx8h2ptRhjICnQGD36vNCY9donkRuwBVQyYIQLLxaQJvxyO7v0hf5fV08i0SQQgQsagKr9TXS7yY6M@WEs1uLOYdHUK@DfjHvnu53pt8nWC9o/q0@47BHBdJDTXXRawcJe1BttzQQZJv6n@NZ40vSHDSagLvAzZmg/w2Im2x0uC5CcgyiZjgEvTMKfZjCzi15JWI63iNXwyYLc@RVQBJTqnQgHe1WisrtFxpW2N0ARyoY8RPXWpj7WMxXWMwoW2yjOO1Xt3a9Ni1Unqo9@g1Rl6K/DKYBWdzFDO6pA3OZpj1vO4Btbg9detTo1ME4YlfiNMViehxYsS2z6b9xB9iWdXOzCHPuojXvPvkH) кода ниже, но ряда Тейлора для функции `cos(ax)`.

Смотрите пример ввода/вывода в конце моего ответа после кода.

[Попробовать код онлайн!](https://tio.run/##jVXNbttGEL7zKQYOEJCWTUUFggCio0vaW9FTb0UrbCjaXogiCf64bAsDlpTWaOM4SI@9FOgTqK5VK7Itv8LuE7kzu6RE/dgpD@Rydnb3m2/mm3WjaNf1WXBwf1@vw2GaRkmzXvcC@3ve5ZHX4cwO44M6/dW/Zj/4YdxOvJh7yZOvWJrFzG/74QGLeXrYM4wnPHD9rOPB3pHnpmHcqlh4mKSxx3pVm9tj6WHLMBBAkoDe/svwAH4youy1z92mAfggLvGHmIlb2ZcDeSKHYioHYiZPbBC/y7fyVExkX1yLsbjF0XtAl/fiUoxA/IW2jziDvvR7Ka5xWlyJEU2j9y2u/hmCHWC2OmmOwEz4j147palOiFA8YBaiguIpbF14CbsNZ27eD2MoV3Kce@bgZw8CB2o1Xl1fiUq@k2/kG8T9i5hQBHIAYorg/kWIM/GPmEER26UcynP5K46U8Z0y3uglFNwdul@jzykuHiNPfQp1Iq5wBqOn9W/VHuUOaB6i2wdxA@qoG@RjhseWLOJnBLsFMeXThW0MmTlLxqRtR1ly2H7N3K7ZhTqYHGrQsKyF27GxeFPgmDZxgcddgrhQ0CmhYgomnaoATyg2eUJkqMyr6M4sDeco5B34POtFZpJ2ms2isuApJGGWWuCGQZJW6H4gL4ibjKb1YH7mMAkO8F3xUeHZlLM7hHcu@5ADVSla7zSTSEatYS2zSChhjwB8w7@lwRZsQ/7dFg0L7pYZ5vuFvYraWnKp7ruFrluPkr@sGTF@SDMad1Hur8JelKWeWfzmGxQRE7s7Shif1sX/4r9EivDKqq4SLM@QcfQYULGIEX4nmDGs5A11mzsbBFgqbbyus8I0QrmMlNaUF56iT3igFORwXU80uqEJ0lQXzNUIVuojhtrLoji2obuaSOXhYe8NIHaK1EYxP2Kpp/ul0oRuwHs6Ly3czTGOHcOgoP9UXGEXUL30itoNIMC7OYVFu7yYV/9oWaa2wQOfBx6sqC@MvJjhqaqONyhzp9LitUafQorXR5l6Gtta1qRjHVwRKlkwBAOPTqHHeGCWq9RBbln6XwSpF0MALOgAa5YyKNu5Kr5qTbOFRe/DA2i1QL2KNrd@/UzUe0ydcyb@lr/hcKr7NlYLevWRsEcFtaCBQjbpArIcY3PX0RutJmA9cL0nqMtZKc4PzAY2ApZbSAO50Fmq7dA6L@j4S0zkq0wsM5ovuKzwlDufQnLE/AxpTiEKKXMKSK7cKqjssrVgT1kHuKETEC9Up6dKWmO601Fa@Fv2M@Wqr8QzcYWSLtoG3fqYFSR1gAlFpevDVBayngWo5iG6TEnP8nwTz6/COEZtFYGF@xWeHwtzfozypX6/GuqxcX//Aj6znxvP7Mbz/wA)

```
// https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Natural_logarithm

#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

class TaylorLog {
public:
    // Конструктор. Вычисления ряда Тейлора для заданных n, a.
    TaylorLog(size_t n, double a) {
        double k = -1;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            // Коэффициент каждого следующего элемента получается из предыдущего путём домножения на -a.
            k *= -a;
            s_.push_back(k / (i + 1));
        }
    }
    // Вывод в поток (например консоль).
    void Dump(std::ostream & sout) const {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < s_.size(); ++i) {
            // Выводим i-й коэффициент плюс x степени (i+1).
            sout << s_[i] << " * x^" << (i + 1);
            if (i + 1 < s_.size())
                sout << " + ";
        }
    }
    // Вычисление ряда Тейлора.
    double Compute(double x) {
        double r = 0, k = 1;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < s_.size(); ++i) {
            // Вычисляется степень x итеративно.
            k *= x;
            // Каждое следующее слагаемое равно коэффициенту домноженному на k (степень x).
            r += s_[i] * k;
        }
        return r;
    }
private:
    std::vector<double> s_;
};

// Перегрузка оператора вывода в поток.
inline std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream & sout, TaylorLog const & tlog) {
    tlog.Dump(sout);
    return sout;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << "Enter n and a: ";
    size_t n = 0;
    double a = 0;
    std::cin >> n >> a;
    // Конструируем объект класса ряда Тейлора.
    TaylorLog tlog(n, a);
    // Выводим ряд в поток.
    std::cout << "Taylor serie for ln(1 + ax): " << tlog << std::endl;
    double x = 0;
    std::cout << "Enter x: ";
    std::cin >> x;
    std::cout << "Taylor serie value at point " << x << ": " << tlog.Compute(x) << std::endl;
    // Вычисляем точное значение используя стандартную std::log(num) функцию.
    std::cout << "Correct value of ln(1 + ax) at point " << x << ": " << std::log(1 + a * x) << std::endl;
}
```

Вывод:

```
Enter n and a: 7 2.5
Taylor serie for ln(1 + ax): 2.5 * x^1 + -3.125 * x^2 + 5.20833 * x^3 + -9.76562 * x^4 + 19.5312 * x^5 + -40.6901 * x^6 + 87.1931 * x^7
Enter x: 0.15
Taylor serie value at point 0.15: 0.31849
Correct value of ln(1 + ax) at point 0.15: 0.318454
```

**Вопрос 2**

[Попробовать код онлайн!](https://tio.run/##lZLdbsIwDIXv8xQWk6Z2f0LiBhWGxAvsFao0DSNScavEmbp1PHsXt0ALaELkpol98vnUjqqqV1VI/GzbB4Oq8LmGpXKUG6SVGEKmdGS13K2EoO9K53oDPkjmKYGfL4QIDOfgw@@gEZXPCqMSAWGFSOTngDEkgGkUvs3@lGC5KtERPEJ2UGRvmI5FIVVW2koqLbzD5ZWmk/HCNKT58uIUspq8RXiirXF99D9q7/AChneTnm8Y/L3H4UC9gvbbAc1pGRyPOLwkG8quqsljpcqaL0m6H9TGGo05hMknyWHW419bLiE6z73AyFXcM7mP3LrpQuzDozBYGNR3MMGdUYehHKxHji8586NTipBfSii850IEO2kwOuo7rCo9dXo@bHXN@8m0nnSF@f1N6/U6Dv3t97NZHJ/koRcFo9v2Dw)

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

typedef uint8_t u8;

class Num {
public:
    Num(u8 n) : n_(n) {}
    Num(Num const & b) : n_(b.n_) {}
    Num & operator = (Num const & b) {
        n_ = b.n_;
        return *this;
    }
    Num & operator = (u8 n) {
        n_ = n;
        return *this;
    }
    Num & operator += (Num const & b) {
        n_ |= b.n_;
        return *this;
    }
    Num operator + (Num const & b) const {
        Num a = *this;
        a += b;
        return a;
    }
private:
    friend std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream &, Num const &);
    u8 n_ = 0;
};

inline std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream & s, Num const & n) {
    return (s << size_t(n.n_));
}

int main() {
    std::cout << std::hex << "0x" << (Num(0xAA) + Num(0x33)) << std::endl;
}
```

Вывод:

```
0xbb
```

Comment: Не могли бы Вы закомментировать первую работу. Не совсем понимаю что там происходит.

Comment: @Onleg, да сейчас закомментирую, ждите.

Comment: @Onleg добавил комментарии в коде первого вопроса. Второй не комментировал, т.к. не просили.

Comment: @Onleg Когда завершим решение задачек, не забудьте поставить моему ответу +1 голос и зачесть его. А то чего то на него сильно в минус голоса поставили, даже обидно, вроде решение хорошее. Проголосовать +1 и поставить птичку можно слева вверху возле начала моего ответа, там стрелка вверх и птичка, птичка это для приёма ответа моего как зачтённого правильного ответа на вопрос.

Comment: Будет сделано, можно еще вопрос по этому же заданию. Насколько сильно измениться код если по условию будет cos(ax) Чтоб уж точно осознать задание

Comment: @Onleg Вот [реализовал вариант](https://godbolt.org/z/ddrePo) такого же кода для `cos(ax)`

Comment: @Arty имхо, вы, конечно, молодец. Решение хорошее, и помощь другим людям безусловно хорошо. Но своим ответом вы показываете, что в поведении автора нет ничего плохого. И новые участники, увидев это, будут думать, что вопросы-задания на ruSO - норма. А это уже не есть хорошо.